# Why is Pearson's r suboptimal for a correlations involving an ordinal variable?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

I’ve had a long search through this site and surprisingly haven’t been able to find anything that directly answers this question. I’m interested both in the case where Pearson’s r is used for an correlation between two ordinal variables, and also the case where it's used for a correlation between one ordinal and one continuous variable.

The general advice on this site is to use either Spearman’s rho or Kendall’s tau, and there are many questions that speak to this, [perhaps most notably this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/pearsons-or-spearmans-correlation-with-non-normal-data). @rob-hyndman’s answer to that question states “Pearson's correlation is a measure of the linear relationship between two continuous random variables.” This contrasts somewhat [with this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/591766/9162), at which @nick-cox gives a very nice answer to a somewhat related question that mentions “whether the variables are continuous is mostly irrelevant”.

Also, why is using Pearson's r on a continuous variable and a binary variable (the Point-Biserial correlation) considered fine, when using Pearson's r on a continuous variable and an ordinal variable is not?

Comment: Pearson r assumes that the meaurement level is scale, aka metrical, that is, interval or ratio. In such a scale you can add values, subtract values, compute average. Ordinal scale is (quantitative) categorical: the precise distance between levels is undefined (so far). You don't know if "2"-"1" is the same difference as "3"-"2", for example. Hence you cannot do those arithmetics with these levels.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "suboptimal"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with Pearson correlation on ordinal data is that it's derived from  covariance, and covariance is a statement about the **differences** between the observed data and the mean of the data (or an estimate of the mean). Therefore Pearson correlation only has a sensible interpretation when differences have a sensible interpretation.

In categorical/ordinal data, the difference between any two levels is meaningless. Therefore any statement about differences on such data is likewise meaningless.

In terms of the [levels of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) system, *not* having a guaranteed meaning for differences is one of the essential characteristics that distinguishes "ordinal" and "interval" scale data. So this meaninglessness is definitional and fundamental. If differences were meaningful, then your data would definitionally not be ordinal scale, it would be interval scale (so named because *intervals*, i.e. differences, would have meaning)

#### Example

Consider that you could encode "small", "medium", "large" categories as 1,2,5 or 0,2,3. Both encodings correctly encode the same ordinal levels, but the differences between levels are arbitrary and have no meaning. Consider the following dataset:

```
 X1 | X2
----|----
 sm | md
 md | md
 sm | sm
 lg | md
```

If you encode this using the 1,2,5 system, you get a correlation of 0.44. But if you encode this using the 0,2,3 system, you get a correlation of 0.56.

Demo in R:

```r
x1 <- c("sm", "md", "sm", "lg")
x2 <- c("md", "md", "sm", "md")

encoding1 <- c(sm = 1, md = 2, lg = 5)
encoding2 <- c(sm = 0, md = 2, lg = 3)

cor(encoding1[x1], encoding1[x2])  # 0.4402255
cor(encoding2[x1], encoding2[x2])  # 0.5555556
```

The arbitrary encoding of differences leads to arbitrary results when working with differences.

#### Continuity is not important

Note that continuity is not at all an important characteristic, as suggested by Nick Cox in the quote you included in your question.

Consider Spearman correlation, which is equivalent to Pearson correlation computed on the ranks of the data. Ranks are not continuous! But the difference between any two pair of ranks does have a consistent meaning across all pairs of ranks, so it's perfectly reasonable to talk about differences between ranks, and therefore it's reasonable to talk about the correlation between two collections of ranks.

Spearman correlation on the example above *does* produce a consistent and non-arbitrary result. This is precisely because the differences between levels are themselves consistent and non-arbitrary.

Demo in R:

```r
cor(encoding1[x1], encoding1[x2], method = "spearman")  # 0.5443311
cor(encoding2[x1], encoding2[x2], method = "spearman")  # 0.5443311
```

#### Summary

I would say that Pearson correlation is wholly inappropriate for ordinal categorical data. You can compute the quantity if your ordinal levels are encoded as real numbers, but that quantity cannot be interpreted in the usual way. One practical manifestation of this problem is that the computed quantity will change whenever you change the ordinal encoding system that you use, even if the underlying data is exactly the same.

This is because ordinal data does not have a meaningful concept of differences between values, it only has a concept of ordering. Correlation depends on differences to have meaning. Therefore if differences don't have meaning, correlation cannot have meaning.

If you can interpret your data as "interval scale" data instead of "ordinal scale", with meaningful differences between levels, then you can use correlation. Or if you can transform your ordinal-scale data to something interval-scale (as with ranks in Spearman correlation) then you can compute the correlation on the transformed data.

If we define "optimality" as "having a real-world interpretation and producing results that are not sensitive to irrelevant changes in encoding", then yes, Pearson correlation is suboptimal.